# Running background task in Kotlin using coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to start a daemon "thread" to update a boolean `flag` in the background. The main thread will periodically check the value of this `flag` to determine whether it needs to perform an action or not. I was considering coroutines but I'm not entirely sure if it fits the purpose given that this won't be in a runblock. Any thoughts?

Comment: How would you make the main thread periodically check the flag? This would be simpler with a single coroutine that periodically switches back to the main dispatcher for it to react unless you need to encapsulate these behaviors separately.

Comment: Need more information about your intent and architectural decisions. Coroutines allows you to write async code and non async code, the limits you are concerned about might lay in comon practices (that's why I ask to reveal more info above), proper implementaion of logic with coroutines and others ways to achieve your goal

Comment: Let's say that the main thread is in a while loop, and for every loop, if the condition is true, it does additional work. There's a need to encapsulate this flag logic separately. I'm using a ScheduledExectuorService with a single thread which updates the flag.

Comment: So your main thread is not the Android main thread, or the Swing main thread, etc? This is your own engine for a main thread?

Comment: Yes this isn't Android or swing. Just running on the jvm on my machine

Comment: Looks like this is a textbook case for the observer pattern. Instead of your main thread checking it periodically, I would suggest to spin off a `Coroutine`/`Task` which does it periodically and updates a boolean "observer" variable in the view model. Register an observer, which will get invoked every time the boolean is observed to change. This is essentially a push-based mechanism as opposed to your original idea to do it as a pull-based implementation.

Comment: This isn't for Android so fragments won't apply 

Comment: Yeah. I've changed my comment suggesting an observer pattern (which is provided by Android LiveData as a first-class construct). See if it helps :)

Comment: Yes thanks! I ended up going this route ☺️